# Maxdepth option not working find command in Solaris

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I am creating a script with below commands in solaris

```sh
name=$(date +"%y-%m-%d")
mkdir /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/archive/Advices/EMAIL/$name
find /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/Advices/EMAIL/ -type f -mtime +30   -exec mv {} /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/archive/Advices/EMAIL/$name \;
tar -zcvf /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/archive/Advices/EMAIL/${name}.tar.gz /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/archive/Advices/EMAIL/${name}
find /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/archive/Advices/EMAIL/ -mtime +60 -name "*.tar.gz" -exec rm {} \;
```

`-maxdepth` is giving below error.

```
-bash-4.4$ find /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/Advices/EMAIL/ -type f -mtime +30 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/archive/Advices/EMAIL/$name \;
find: bad option -maxdepth
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
-bash-4.4$
```

Even `-path` is not working.

Is there any workaround here.

My requirement is i want to find files from below directory only and not any subdirectory

```
/cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/Advices/EMAIL/
```

Comment: Does the Solaris man page for `find` say it supports that non-POSIX option?

Answer (score 0):

The find command:

```
find path/to/the/dir -type f -maxdepth 1
```

can be substituted with:

```
find path/to/the/dir/. -not -name . -type d -prune -o -type f
```

The `find` command interprets the sequence above as:

1. Find the directory `path/to/the/dir` recursively.
2. If the name is *not* "." and the type is "directory" then skip (-prune) it.
3. Otherwise (-o) advance to the next condition.

As of the described example, please try to modify the line:

```
find /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/Advices/EMAIL/ -type f -mtime +30 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/archive/Advices/EMAIL/$name \;
```

as:

```
find /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/Advices/EMAIL/. -not -name . -type d -prune -o -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv {} /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/archive/Advices/EMAIL/"$name" \;
```

Comment: Below is working for me now. thanks @tshiono , rowboat , shawn `find /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/Advices/EMAIL/. ! -name . -prune  -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv {} /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/archive/Advices/EMAIL/"$name" \;1

Answer (score 0):

Below is working for me now .
Just to update -not is also not available option in my environment.

```
find /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/Advices/EMAIL/. ! -name . -prune  -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv {} /cms/Oracle/Middleware/dib_common/archive/Advices/EMAIL/"$name" \;
```